# swift - texfield call editingDidBegin after editingDidEnd

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ibaction, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a `tableView cell` with `textfield`, which also show `picker`, where I displaying filtered list of data, and it filter by input symbols. I'm using `IQkeyboardManager` and `McPicker`. 
When user begins editing, `picker` is presenting as modal. Then, if value chosen from picker's list, `picker` is dismissed.

And problem is: when I tap `done` at keyboard (calling `didEndEditing`) at console I see as app calling `didEndEditing` - then `beginEditing`, and then processing lines of code at `@IBAction func editDidBegin(_ sender: UITextField)` again

here is my code:

```
class QuickOrderVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
/* some code */
@IBAction func editDidBegin(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("didBegin")
        /* some code */
        McPicker.showAsPopover(data: [filteredArr], fromViewController: self, sourceView: sender as! UIView, doneHandler: { [weak self] (selections: [Int : String]) -> Void in
            if let first = selections[0]{
                /* some code */
                self?.dismissKeyboard()
                return
            }
            }, cancelHandler: { () -> Void in
                /* some code */
                print("Canceled Popover begin")
                self.dismissKeyboard()
        }, selectionChangedHandler: { (selections: [Int:String], componentThatChanged: Int) -> Void  in
            let newSelection = selections[componentThatChanged] ?? "Failed to get new selection!"
            print("Component \(componentThatChanged) changed value to \(newSelection)")
        })
    }
    var filteredArr = [String]()
    @IBAction func sizeTextEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        /* some code */
        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            McPicker.showAsPopover(data: [filteredArr], fromViewController: self, sourceView: sender as! UIView, doneHandler: { [weak self] (selections: [Int : String]) -> Void in
                if let first = selections[0]{
                    /* some code */
                    print("done Popover edit")
                    self?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    print("done Popover dismiss")
                    /* some code */
                    self?.dismissKeyboard()
                    return
                }
                }, cancelHandler: { () -> Void in
                    /* some code */
                    print("Canceled Popover edit")
                    self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    print("Canceled Popover dismiss")
                    self.dismissKeyboard()
                    return
            }, selectionChangedHandler: { (selections: [Int:String], componentThatChanged: Int) -> Void  in
                let newSelection = selections[componentThatChanged] ?? "Failed to get new selection!"
                print("Component \(componentThatChanged) changed value to \(newSelection)")
            })
        })
    }
    @IBAction func editDidEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("did end")
        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        print("did end - dismiss")
        return
    }
```

and at console:

```
did end // when tap `done` at keyboard
didBegin // why??
did end - dismiss
did end //why duplicate??
did end - dismiss
done Popover edit
done Popover dismiss
```

Comment: Are you really needed the functionality to edit the value of textField with Keyboard?

Comment: @FebinFathah yes, i update filtered list of data as user input something. this part works fine

Comment: When printing the debug lines, you should be adding the `sender` value to the output string. If not now, in the future, you will have multiple calls from different UITextFields that you will need to distinguish.

Comment: @AamirR can you make a suggestion how to change this lines at mcpicker.swift (which actually a cocoapod library)? I also use this picker at another viewcontrollers without this error

Comment: @AamirR oh, I mean what changes should I do to prevent the error? like add `guard `statement or smth?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and identify the variable getting nil while unwrapping.